# Most efficient way to use inheritance in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I've been messing around with some JavaScript inheritance techniques and here's one case in which I'm trying to derive a strong solution.

Here's a simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JgrYu/

**The Issue:** Logically we'd expect the two div's to be both 0's.  But since we're just newing the extended class we don't re-generate our "c" variable.

A potential fix for this is to use Functional inheritance:
http://jsfiddle.net/h8xtz/

```
function mybase() {
    var that = {};
    var c = 0;

    that.hi = function() {
        var ele = $('<div></div>');
        ele.html(c++);
        $('body').append(ele);
    }

    return that;
}

function myextended() {
    var that = mybase();

    that.hi();

    return that;
}

myextended.prototype = new mybase();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = myextended();
    var b = myextended();
})​
```

**However** the issue with this is that we clutter the global namespace and each object duplicates the functional properties when in reality we just want duplication of the private variables.

**So,** what I'm looking for is a better approach than functional inheritance to solve this issue.  I've thought about making a psuedo classical inheritance structure where I separate the private and public variables/functions but I haven't been able to come up with a version with less overhead than the functional inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new set of private variables for each object, you will need to [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the parent's constructor from the child's one. And don't use a instance of the parent as the prototype object for the child, but just an object that inherits from the parent's prototype object. This can be done with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
function myextended() {
    mybase.call(this); // apply the parent's constructor on the new object
    this.hi();
}

myextended.prototype = Object.create(mybase.prototype);
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JgrYu/3/))

Answer (score 0):

How about making the variable a part of the prototype:

```
function mybase() {

    this.hi = function() {
        var ele = $('<div></div>');
        ele.html(this.c++);
        $('body').append(ele);
    }
}

mybase.prototype.c = 0;
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/JgrYu/1/).

Note:  Alternatively you could initialize `this.c` when declaring mybase.

Comment: Only problem with that is then we love the "privateness" of our c variable and the extended class now has access to it.  Meaning if I have a c variable in my extended class it will override it as if it were public.